# React set state and clear state of an object state

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, if-statement, setstate

i have `error` state object to validate form inputs :

```
  const [error, setError] = useState({
    nameArErr: "",
    nameEnErr: "",
    accountNumberErr: "",
    ageErr: "",
    phoneNumberErr: "",
    hireDateErr: "",
    birthDateErr: "",
  });

  const handleAdd = (e) => {

    setError({});

    if (nameAr.current.value.length < 11) {
      setError({ ...error, nameArErr: "please enter your full name" });
    }

    if (nameEn.current.value.length < 11) {
      setError({ ...error, nameEnErr: "please enter your full name" });
    }

    if (accountNumber.current.value === "") {
      setError({ ...error, accountNumberErr: "account number can't be empty" });
    }

    if (
      Number(age.current.value) > 60 ||
      Number(age.current.value) < 18 ||
      age.current.value === ""
    ) {
      setError({ ...error, ageErr: "please enter a valid age" });
    }

    if (phoneNumber.current.value.length !== 10) {
      setError({
        ...error,
        phoneNumberErr: "please enter a valid phone number",
      });
    }

    if (hireDate.current.value === "") {
      setError({ ...error, hireDateErr: "hire date can't be empty" });
    }

    if (birthDate.current.value === "") {
      setError({ ...error, birthDateErr: "birth date can't be empty" });
    }

    console.log(error);


  };
```

my problem with code is :

**first** if all `if statements` are true it will not `setState` all at once it will rather `setState` of the last true `if statement`

**second**   `setError({});` works only if all `statements` are wrong, but what i want is let's say the function is triggered and the first `if statement` applies then `nameArErr` value would be `"please enter your full name"`, then suppose the function is triggered again and the statement doesn't apply anymore, then `nameArErr` should be empty by this line of code `setError({});` but it doesn't until all statements are wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an array/object to store the errors and at the end a setState with the array/object (or nothing if there is no error):

```
  const [error, setError] = useState({});

  const handleAdd = (e) => {
    let errors = {};
    if (nameAr.current.value.length < 11) {
        errors.nameArErr = "please enter your full name";
    }

    if (nameEn.current.value.length < 11) {
        errors.nameEnErr= "please enter your full name";
    }

    if (accountNumber.current.value === "") {
        errors.accountNumberErr = "account number can't be empty";
    }

    if (
      Number(age.current.value) > 60 ||
      Number(age.current.value) < 18 ||
      age.current.value === ""
    ) {
        errors.ageErr = "please enter a valid age";
    }

    if (phoneNumber.current.value.length !== 10) {
        errors.phoneNumberErr = "please enter a valid phone number";
    }

    if (hireDate.current.value === "") {
        errors.hireDateErr = "hire date can't be empty";
    }

    if (birthDate.current.value === "") {
        errors.birthDateErr = "birth date can't be empty";
    }
    setError(errors);
  };
```